# Changing 252 WPAD option on Windows DHCP server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, proxy, dhcp

I am replacing our old ISA server with a new server based on Forefront TMG.

On the DHCP server (Windows 2003) I can see that the DHCP Option 252 is pointing to the old address.

I have changed the predefined options for the server to make it point to the new proxy, however, all reservations and clients are still going through the old one.

We have a pool of dynamic addresess and also a buch of reserved ones. I have tried deleting a reservation and creating it again but it still points to the old server.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. The 252 option I was setting was defined also at the Scope Level on the DHCP manager and it was the one taking effect. I changed it and it's now working fine.